# How to make a wordpress menu button a link to another site

Tags: wordpress

I have a Web site that is designed with wordpress. I want that when a user clicks on one of my menu's buttons(for example home, or "about us") the page be redirected to another website! how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Custom Links` option in WP Menu Tab. There you can set the external / custom menu as show [here](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a5s3i979).

Also have a look at [WP External Links](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-external-links/) WP plugin to have multiple option in setting up the external link to your WP site menu.